# which driver can control 4-5 motors, different types of sensors, speakers?

Tags: gpio, driver, pwm

I am planning to make a robot car with various functions and I want to control 2-3 DC motors with hall sensor, 2-3 servo motors, sensors like [these](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/Free-Shipping-37-in-1-Sensor-Kit-For-Arduino-Starters-keyes-brand/1328769158.html?spm=2114.13010308.0.0.9izhgL) and some electronic components like a speaker, microphone, LED lights, etc. I found some driver like L298N, but it can control only 2 motors. Can I control sensors and electric components directly with raspberry pi? If not, please suggest me a good driver that can control all of these. I am relatively new to all these.

Comment: It seems unlikely that you'll find a single product which accommodates DC motors *and* servos *and* sensors *and* audio *and* lights *and*... who, aside from you in this one special case, would need it? You'll have an easier time of it sourcing individual components for individual purposes - DC motor driver, A-to-D converters for the sensors, amplifier board for the speaker, sound card for the mic, driver for the LEDs (or use individually addressable LEDs). In addition to being easier to source, it's much easier to maintain a modular platform than a monolithic one.

Comment: I want to accommodate them in a small place, too many drivers would make it messy.

Comment: Try the 4tronix Picon Zero - http://4tronix.co.uk/store/index.php?rt=product/product&product_id=552 It might suit your needs

Comment: Can I use Arduino Uno as an alternative to it?

Answer (score 3):

The most capable motor controller board that gets closest to what you require is called the 4tronix Picon Zero.

[image: 4tronix Picon Zero]

As you can see from the picture, it allows you to drive 2 DC motors (bottom right) and has outputs (left) that you can configure as servo outputs. There are also a number of inputs (which can take both digital *and* analog signals.

You can [get it from 4tronix](http://4tronix.co.uk/store/index.php?rt=product/product&product_id=552) or [The Pi Hut](https://thepihut.com/products/picon-zero-intelligent-robotics-controller-for-raspberry-pi?variant=18239964292).

I reviewed the Picon Zero over [on my blog](http://www.recantha.co.uk/blog/?p=14715).

Comment: Can I use this -(https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1r1vMNFXXXXXmXXXXq6xXFXXX8/206232166/HTB1r1vMNFXXXXXmXXXXq6xXFXXX8.jpg?size=92119&height=800&width=800&hash=9a7490f809ed148d29883c888ae29401) motor with this driver.

Comment: I don't know I'm afraid. I have no idea what kind of power requirements there are for that motor.

Comment: Can I use Arduino Uno as a alternative to it?

Comment: I suppose you could, but I'm not an expert on Arduino I'm afraid. I'm sure there's a stack exchange for it though!

Answer (score 0):

You need a motor driver board for the DC motors (and for stepper motors).

The servo motors can be driven (but not powered) directly from the Pi.

General digital sensors can normally be driven direct from the Pi.

You need additional hardware (an ADC) to talk to analogue sensors.